# Composer requires sudo for simple -V command

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

I'm trying to set up Composer for use with Heroku, but am running into problems. I've followed the download steps [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) which generates the composer.phar file. I then moved it to `/usr/local/bin/composer` per the instructions [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally). Now when running `composer` from CLI I get the error

`Could not open input file: /Users/myusername/.composer/composer.phar`

`sudo composer -V` gets me the version number,but with the warning

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
```

The link seems unrelated to a simple `-V` command, which I can't imagine I should need to `sudo` to run anyway. I've done this installation pretty much by the book, but it seems like this isn't right.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect non-root users do not have execute permissions.. From a shell on my system, I get...

```
 ls -al /usr/local/bin/composer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root user 1201562 Dec  8  2015 /usr/local/bin/composer
```

eg; Full perms for root, read & execute for everyone else. You may need to ..

```
 sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer
```